# Return a List from Tuple of dual values via Linq query

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections, tuples

I have a list of tuples with dual values:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> Descriptions;
```

And I keep adding content to this, like so:

```
Descriptions.Add (new Tuple<string, string> ("max", "some description"));
Descriptions.Add (new Tuple<string, string> ("joe", "some description"));
Descriptions.Add (new Tuple<string, string> ("jane", "some description"));
Descriptions.Add (new Tuple<string, string> ("max", "some other description"));
```

I want to retrieve a list using Linq where `Item1` in the tuple is a certain value like, say, `"max"`. I could use this code:

```
var s = Descriptions.Where (x => x.Item1 == "max");
```

but this will assign *s* a list of tuples, which I don't want. I just want a list of the description strings, that is, it should return a `list<string>` with all the descriptions associated with the `Item1` string `"max"`.

Comment: [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Select`:

```
var s = Descriptions.Where (x => x.Item1 == "max").Select(y => y.Item2);
```

That will return an `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a list, you need to also add `ToList` at the end:

```
var s = Descriptions.Where (x => x.Item1 == "max").Select(y => y.Item2).ToList();
```

Or you can use Query syntax:

```
var s = from d in Descriptions
        where d.Item1 == "max"
        select d.Item2;
```

That's the same as the first option. In fact, the compiler will translate query syntax to linq's extension methods.

Answer (score 3):

After `Where()` you can use `Select()` method to get only `description` which in your case will be `Item2` of `Tuple` and you would need to do like:

```
var s = Descriptions.Where(x => x.Item1 == "max")
                    .Select(x=>x.Item2); // projects only Description
```

This will return you all elements in form of `IEnumerable<string>` which have `Item1` having value `"max"` and if you really want to get it as `List<string>`, then you can add `ToList()` method call at end.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The other answer however is more apt for my situation.

Comment: yes, glad to help and it's your call :) both would work.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the other solutions try using a dictionary instead of a list of tuples. by the looks of your content this is more what you might want (only if your names are unique).

```
Dictionary<string, string> NameDesc = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            NameDesc.Add("max", "desc1");
            NameDesc.Add("tim", "desc2");

            var description = NameDesc["max"];
            var maxExists = NameDesc.ContainsKey("max");
```

Comment: The question clearly states the value "max" twice in the sample data. A dictionary will not alloe that...